# apache Poi / npoi - get a sheetidentifier from a sheet

Tags: apache-poi, npoi

I'm trying to construct a Ref3dPxg - and need a sheetIdentifier from it - I have a sheet, but can't figure out how to construct it in a nice way -  I've tried
`new SheetIdentifier( "", new NameIdentifier( mySheet.name, false))`, which works, but there has to be a better way?

Comment: Generally you don't construct either of those classes, but let FormulaParser do it all for you. Why do you think you need to do that all manually?

Comment: Because I’m writing a tool that “rewrites” formulas for a particular reason - so I’m parsing a formula and replacing certain ptg elements with new ones, then rendering it back as a formula